# How many good integers less than $10^n$ are there?

Tags: proof-explanation, generating-functions

> Positive integer is good if it has $1$ as a digit. How many good integers less than $10^n$ are there?

The problem is trivial and it solution is easy to find. I'm asking about the method of solving with GF. Let's make an exponential generating function $$H(x) = ({x\over 1!} + {x^2\over 2!}+ {x^3\over 3!}+...) (1+{x\over 1!} + {x^2\over 2!}+ {x^3\over 3!}+...)^9$$ 
$$ = (e^x-1)e^{9x}$$

> **My question here is**, why this function really "recognise" good numbers? Namely the same GF is for any other number. Wouldn't it be more correcly to write $$H(x) = ({a\over 1!} + {a^2\over 2!}+ {a^3\over 3!}+...) (1+{x\over 1!} + {x^2\over 2!}+ {x^3\over 3!}+...)^9$$ 
>   $$ = (e^a-1)e^{9x}$$ or even $$H(x) = (e^{x_1}-1) e^{x_2}e^{x_3}... e^{x_{10}}$$
>   and of course such GF doesn't really help much here, or does it?

Comment: Why do you think it _should_ recognise exactly good numbers? Your question makes no sense as it stands. (And of course the number of integers less than $10^n$ that contain at least one $1$ as a digit is just $10^n-9^n$.)

Comment: I don't understand neither comment. Sorry.

Comment: The reason why the EGF is $e^{10x} - e^{9x}$ is because there are $10^n - 9^n$ such numbers. The reason why the EGF is not $e^{9x + a} - e^{9x}$ is because there are not $e^a9^n - 9^n$ such numbers. Why do you think it is "more correct" to write the EGF differently?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm new at the subject, I'm just asking to clearify my  thoughts. @TrevorGunn

Comment: You want the coefficient of $x^n$ to be the number of good numbers divided by $n!$. What is the role of $a$? How do you extract the number of good numbers from your generating functions?

Comment: If $$c_{i,j}{a^ix^j\over i!j!}$$ then it would be $c_{1,n-1}+c_{2,n-1}+...+c_{n,0}$@TrevorGunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start, because these are exponential generating functions, the correct way to extract coefficients would be$^\dagger$

$$ \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} \frac{a^ix^j}{i!j!} \longmapsto c_{0,n} + \binom n1 c_{1,n-1} + \binom n2 c_{2,n-2} + \binom n3 c_{3,n-3} + \dots + c_{n,0}. $$

If $n = i + j$ these terms are

$$ \binom{i+j}i c_{ij} = \frac{(i+j)!}{i!j!} c_{i,j}.$$

Then this sum $\sum \binom ni c_{i,n-i}$ is the same as the coefficient of $x^n/n!$ when you set $a = x$.

$$ \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} \frac{a^ix^j}{i!j!} \mapsto \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} \frac{x^{i+j}}{i!j!} = \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} \frac{(i+j)!}{i!j!} \frac{x^{i + j}}{(i + j)!} $$

Now collecting all the terms where $i + j = n$ we get

$$ \sum_n \left(\sum_{i + j = n} \binom{i + j}{i} c_{i,j} \right) \frac{x^n}{n!}. $$

---

$^\dagger$ The simple reason why we add the binomial coefficients (for EGFs) is they make the formula work out correctly as you can see above.

The more involved reason that explains this better is that exponential generating functions correspond to putting structures on sets. In this example the sets are the decimal places and the structures are the digits. Specifically:

$$ \mathcal{A} = \text{the digit 1}, \\ \mathcal{X} = \text{all other digits}. $$

Here the EGF of $\mathcal{A}$ is $e^a - 1$ because there is a unique way to make a number with $n$-decimal places where every digit is $1$ and we subtract $1$ to exclude $n = 0$. The EGF of $\mathcal{X}$ is $e^{9x}$ since there are $9^n$ numbers with $n$-decimal places that don't contain a $1$.

When we multiply the structures $\mathcal{A} * \mathcal{X}$, what that means in EGF-land is to partition the decimal places into two sets, put an $\mathcal{A}$-structure on one set (i.e. make those digits 1) and put an $\mathcal{X}$-structure on the remaining digits (i.e. make those digits any other digit). For example the number $11316$ corresponds to taking a partition $\{1,2,4\} \cup \{3,5\}$ of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, putting $1$'s in spots $1,2,4$ and putting non-$1$'s in spots $3,5$. By removing the $a^0$ term from the EGF for $\mathcal{A}$ we are disallowing a partition where there are zero $1$'s.

It is exactly this partitioning that gives you the binomial coefficients because there are $\binom{n}{i}$ ways to partition the decimal places to give you $i$ $1$'s and $n - i$ non-$1$'s.

---

If we wanted to, we could track every digit by a different variable. This would give the EGF $e^{x_0}(e^{x_1} - 1)e^{x_2}e^{x_3} \cdots e^{x_9}$. The coefficient $c_{i_0,i_1,\dots,i_9}$ counts numbers with $i_k$ digits equal to $k$.

To get the number we are interested in, we want to collect all tuples where $i_0 + i_1 + \dots + i_9 = n$. These correspond to all the ways to partition the decimal of a number with $n$-decimal places into $10$ sets where we then put $0$'s in the first set of decimal places and $1$'s into the second and so on.

The number of ways of partitioning $n$ into sets of size $i_0, i_1, \dots, i_9$ with $i_0 + \dots + i_9 = n$ is by definition given by the [multinomial coeficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients) equal to $\binom n{i_0,\dots,i_9} = \frac{n!}{i_0! \cdots i_9!}$. As above, the sum

$$ \sum_{i_0 + \dots + i_9 = n} = \binom n{i_0,\dots,i_9} c_{i_0,\dots,i_9} $$

is obtained by setting all the variables $x_0 = x_1 = \dots = x_9 = x$ and looking at the coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: Aha, formaly we should not write $x$ for each digit at the begining, but at the end, when calulating the coefficient, it happend that we could "easly" calulate it if we put all variables are the same?

Comment: And this works every time?

Comment: @Aqua It works every time when the formula is written as $\sum \binom{n}{i} c_{i,n-i}$, yes.

Comment: Let me see if I undrestand it correctly. If we have words of lenght $n$ with letters $a$ and $b$ and $b$ appears even times, then correct GF would be $$(1+x+x^2/2!+...)(1+y^2/2!+y^4/4!+...)$$ But when caluclating the coefficient we see that it would be usefull to put $x=y$, and thus we can do that the beging?

Comment: That is correct @Aqua

Comment: Or if we want to express 100 as a sums of 1,3 and 5 then correct GF would be $$(1+x+x^2+...)(1+y^3+y^6+...)(1+z^5+z^{10}+...)$$ But when caluclating the coefficient we see that it would be usefull to put $x=y=z$, and thus we can do that the beging?

Comment: Yes, that is also right.

Comment: Thank you, do you have any idea about this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3480086/issue-about-the-generating-function